# Can't access Rails server on host using Windows 7 XP Mode - but I can ping

Tags: networking, microsoft-virtual-pc, windows-xp-mode

I'm trying to develop a Rails app, and I'm using the Windows XP mode (Windows Virtual PC) under Windows 7 to allow testing under Internet Explorer 8.

I have XP Mode setup to use the host's network card, and can freely access the internet, and ping in both directions. I have (temporarily!) turned off Windows firewall on both machines.

I'm running a Rails server on port 3000 of the host, and have specified that it should bind to the host's IP (rather than 0.0.0.0). However, I cannot view the app from IE8 on the XP Mode VM (pointing it to :3000).

Any suggestions what might be wrong?

Comment: IF you are trying to develop, why are you using IE8? More then main job is to write model/controllers code rather then views. So you can write your code/test it and after that just upload it to herolu, so you could test your views

Comment: Because I've had a bug report that it doesn't work properly in IE8, so I need to point a local IE8 at it to debug. However, I suppose you're right that I could point IE8 at a staging version running live...

Comment: There is "portable" versions of each IE versions, so your best option would be to download and use it, instead of virtual machine.
Here is the first on google http://tredosoft.com/Multiple_IE?page=6. Also try this http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage, and this http://finalbuilds.com/iecollection.htm